# Why it is hard for `xgboost` to learn periodic functions?

Tags: regression, boosting

In this simple example, I try to train a `xgboost` regressor to learn a periodic function:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBRegressor as r
size = 1000
sine_x = np.linspace(1, size, size).reshape(size, 1)
sine_y = np.sin(sine_x) + 0.3 * np.random.uniform(0, 1)

sine_model = r(max_depth = 5, 
              n_estimators = 1)
sine_model.fit(sine_x, sine_y)
sine_model.get_booster().dump_model('sine_model.txt', with_stats=True)

square_x = np.linspace(1, size, size).reshape(size, 1)
square_y = np.square(square_x) + 0.3 * np.random.uniform(0, 1)
square_model = r(max_depth = 5, 
                 n_estimators = 1)
square_model.fit(square_x, square_y)
square_model.get_booster().dump_model('square_model.txt', with_stats=True)
```

From the result, when the training dataset is sampled from $y = x^2$, `xgboost` does well in the sense that it divides the instances of a parent node evenly to each of its child nodes.

However, when faced with the dataset sampled from $y = \text{sin}x$, the binary trees grow in each step are totally unbalanced, almost all the instances of a parent node will go into one of the child nodes.

How to intuitively understand this?